# Using Rownum and OrderBy in HQL

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by, hql, rownum

I am trying to use `RowNum` with `Orderby` in my HQL. Underlying Database is Oracle.
As expected `Rownum` executes prior to ordering (which I dont want).

In SQL this can be done using `Subselect` in the from clause but how do i achieve this in HQL without affecting the performance. Also HQL doesn't allow Subqueries in the from clause. 
Tried:

```
setFirstResult(resultsetLimit)
setMaxResults(resultsetLimit)
setFetchSize(resultsetLimit)
```

and its slowing down the performance terribly.

I am no Hibernate expert so please excuse if i am missing anything or doing anything grave.
Also at this point i have no option but to use HQL .

Answer (score 1):

**HQL supports subselects and subqueries.**

`For databases that support subselects, Hibernate supports subqueries within queries. A subquery must be surrounded by parentheses (often by an SQL aggregate function call). Even correlated subqueries (subqueries that refer to an alias in the outer query) are allowed.`

As told in the community documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries).

Comment: "HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses." Also Subquery in select clause should return single value...In my case there are multiple values.. Thanks for the answer thou

Comment: As your query gets complicated, try to moving it to **SQL, function or a stored procedure** which will be easy maintain. You can accept the answer if it is helpful.